# Issue with wildcards into arguments of a Bash function

Tags: bash, function, shell, diff

From the following [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111495/how-to-diff-multiple-files-across-directories), I tried to use the following solution to compare a group of source files (here fortran90 = *.f90).

To do this and see the source which are different, I have put into my ~/.bashrc :

```
function diffm { for file in "$1"/"$2"; do diff -qs "$file" "$3"/"${file##*/}"; done ;}
```

But unfortunately, if I am in the current directory for argument `$1`, i.e by execute :

```
$ diffm . '*.f90' ../../dir2
```

The result is : `impossible to access to './*.f90'`. However, the sources `*.f90` exist but wildcards are not taken into account.

Surely a problem with double quotes on arguments of my function (`$1`, `$2`, `$3`)?

More generally, this function doesn't work well.

How can I modify this function in order to make it work in all cases, even being in the current directory "`.`" for  the first argument `$1` or the third `$3`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filename generation does not occur within quotes. Hence, you pass the literal string `*.f90` to the function, and this string is used there literally too. If you know for sure that there is exactly one f90 files in your directory, don't use quotes and write

```
diffm . *.f90 ../../dir2
```

Things get ugly if the file name has a space embedded (which, BTW, is one reason why I prefer Zsh over bash - you don't have to care about this in Zsh). To deal with this case, you could do a

```
myfile=*.f90
diffm . "$myfile" ../../dir2
```

But sooner or later, you will be bitten by the fact, that for whatever reason, you have more than one f90 file, and your strategy will break. Therefore, a better solution would be to use a loop, which also works for the border case of having only one file:

```
iterating=0
for myfile in *.f90
do
    if ((iterating == 0))
    then
      ((iterating+=1))
      diffm . "$myfile" ../../dir2
    elif [[ ! -f $myfile ]]
    then
      echo "No files matching $myfile in this directory"
    else
      echo "ERROR: More than one f90-file. Don't know which one to diff" 1>&2
    fi
done
```

The `elif` part just cares for the case that you don't have any f90 files. In this case, the loop body is executed once, and `myfile` contains the wildcard pattern.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Is there a way to keep my original bash function (into my first post)  and find a way to have an argument which represents actually the wildcard of different files with the same extension, here a list of Fortran90 files : I would like to generalize it to different extensions, that's why I would like to convert `*.f90` into a shell script argument : in my original post, this is the argument `$2` but double quote it doesn't seem to be enough. Regards

Comment: Fixed by simply doing : `for file in "$1"/$2;
                   do diff -q "$file" "$3"/"${file##*/}"; done ;`

Comment: Next step : find a way to get rid of the prresence or not of slash in the names of the 2 directories.

Comment: Please start a new thread on SO if you have a new question. You can enter a link to this question if you think it helps in understanding.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood what you are trying to do, this should work

```
diffm () {
    dir="$1"; shift
    for file in "$@"; do
        filename=$(basename "$file")
        diff -qs "$file" "$dir/$filename"
    done
}
```

Usage

```
diffm ../../dir2 ./*.f90
```

Comment: Note: all these variables should be made `local`.