# Compare same type of files from 2 diferent directories : zshrc function

Tags: bash, zsh, diff, wildcard, zshrc

I have posted a long time ago a question about how to compare same type (extension) files from 2 different directories:

[Issue with wildcards into arguments of a Bash function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60294242/issue-with-wildcards-into-arguments-of-a-bash-function)

Under `bash` shell, everything is working fine but now, I am under `zsh` shell and the function below doesn't work any more:

```
function diffm() {for file in "$1"/$2; do diff -q "$file" "$3"/"${file##*/}"; done ;}
```

I get the following error:

```
$ diffm dir1 *.f90 dir2
diff: camb.f90/bessels.f90: Not a directory
```

`camb.f90` and `bessels.f90` are in the same directory, it is a very strange error.

I would like to use it like this (like under `bash` shell):

```
$ diffm . *.f90 ../../dir2
```

Is there a workaround to fix this?

### Update

Here a working version on `bash shell` of this function:

```
function diffm() {
  # First dir
  dir1="$1"
  # Second dir
  dir2="${@: -1}"
  # Add slash if needed
  [[ "$dir1" != */ ]] && dir1=$dir1"/"
  [[ "$dir2" != */ ]] && dir2=$dir2"/"
  # Wildcard filenames
  files=( "$dir1"${@:2:$#-2} )
  # Compare the files
  for file in "${files[@]}"
    do
      diff -q "$file" "$dir2""${file##*/}"
    done;
  }
```

I am looking for the equivalent for `zsh shell`.

Comment: Would you please elaborate what's not working? How about some error messages?

Comment: @paladin . I have added the error : it seems that command interprets like it was a directory. Regards

Comment: Are you sure that the `/` in `for file in "$1"/$2;` is correct? `for file in $1 $2;` gives a more logical answer. PS you should write variable names always in CAPITALS, for better readability.

Comment: @paladin It's generally considered best practice to only upper-case environment variables, not private shell variables. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization

Comment: @paladin to respond to your question about the `/`, I make sure before to not put no slash in my command line, i.e I do a : `diffm . *.f90 ../../dir2` without slash on `dir1` and `dir2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should restructure the order of arguments :

```
function diffm() {
    local dir2="$1" dir1="$2"; shift 2
    for file; do 
        diff -q "$dir1/$file" "$dir2/$file"
    done 
}

diffm ../../dir2 . *.f90
```

zsh version :

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

function diffm() {
    setopt nullglob
    local dir1="$1" files="$2" dir2="$3" file1 file2
    for file1 in "$dir1"/${~files}; do
        file2="${file1##*/}"
        diff -q "$file1" "$dir2/$file2"
    done
}

diffm dir1 "*.f90" dir2
```

Comment: Thanks, this doesn't work under zsh shell. I provide in update a working version for bash. I am looking for the equivalent working under zsh. Regards

Comment: Your `zsh` version works fine, thanks !